# sql query to get row with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to get rows from table a that unique_key column is in table b in the same time, unique_key is not exist in table c.
So If I write table,

```
table a 
+----+------+-----------+
| id | Name | int_value |
+----+------+-----------+
| a1 | aa   |         1 |
| a2 | bb   |         2 |
| a3 | cc   |         5 |
+----+------+-----------+
table b
+----+------+-----------+
| id | Name |unique_key |
+----+------+-----------+
| a1 | aa   |        u1 |
| a2 | bb   |        u2 |
| a3 | cc   |        u5 |
+----+------+-----------+
table c 
+----+------+-----------+
| id | Name |unique_key |
+----+------+-----------+
| c1 | aa   |        u1 |
| c2 | bb   |        u2 |
| c3 | cc   |        u3 |
+----+------+-----------+
```

As a result, I want to get

```
id name int_value b.unique_key
a3 cc   5         u5
```

because u5 is not exist in table c.
I tried these sqls, but none of them get me correct result.
What would you do?

```
SELECT a.*, b.unique_key
FROM a
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id FROM b ) b
ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT unique_key FROM c ) c
ON b.unique_key <> c.unique_key;

SELECT a.*, b.unique_key, c.unique_key
FROM a
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id FROM b ) b
ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT unique_key FROM c ) c
ON b.unique_key = c.unique_key
WHERE c.unique_key IS NULL;
```

Comment: can you explain more about your goal here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below way -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb308527781c5be146a7e9c9fc34f2e4)**

```
SELECT a.*, b.unique_key
FROM a JOIN b 
ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c 
ON b.unique_key = c.unique_key
where c.unique_key is null
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  Name    int_value   unique_key
a3  cc       5           u5
```

Comment: `ON b.unique_key = c.unique_key
where c.unique_key is null`
what `c.unique_key is null` mean? there's no data that `c.unique_key is null` i think

Comment: @JunoJ, check here without the where clause  - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d1250b8fae296075a329e0e145b82765

Comment: Thank you. I checked the result : ) but my question is why unique_key of 3rd row became null o,o

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT a.*, b.unique_key
FROM a JOIN  b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM c 
                 WHERE b.unique_key = c.unique_key);
```

Answer (score 1):

another way is to use NOT IN

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.int_value, b.unique_key
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.unique_key NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT c.unique_key FROM c)
```

result
`id: a3, name: cc, int_value: 5, unique_key: u5`